# DNS resolution warm up in android

Tags: android, dns

I have a broadcast receiver watching the wifi state and sending an http request to me server when it becomes enabled. The problem that I have is that when I run the code under debugger  it works just fine, but when I run the same code without a debugger, it throws an exception.

The exception indicates that the failure is actually the DNS resolution failure - it fails to resolve the DNS name.

I decided that even though the system fired the 'enabled' event, the DNS resolver is not fully initialized yet and added a 10sec delay before the attempt to send my request and this resolved the issue, but I am really uncomfortable with this solution. Even though in my case it does not really matter, 10 sec seems too long. A bigger question will 10 sec be enough on all platforms?

Another solution would be to intercept this particular exception and try again. The question is - how many retries?

My question is - what's the best way to wait until the DNS resolver is fully initialized? Is there an event or a notification I can subscribe to?